# How to check all checkboxs in list in android

Tags: android, checkbox, set

I have one problem in code that is am using check box's in list view and and i have another check to set check and unchecked all check box's in my list presently am able to check all item's but problem is it only showing all check box's checked and return's how many box'x checked.
Main file: 
 public class Take1 extends Activity {

```
    EditText dataf,ed2,topic;
    ListView lv;
    Spinner sp,datesp,classno;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad,ad2;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    String spitem;
    Button speak,date,from,to;
    MediaRecorder mrecorder;
    static final int check=111;
    private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private static final int FROM_TIME = 1;
    private static final int TO_TIME = 2;
    int total,pre,ab,cal=0;
    TextView present;
    //database
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cr;
    CheckBox checkall;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.take);
        topic=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.taketopic);
        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.takespinner1);
        datesp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.takedatespinner2);
        classno=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.noofperiods);
        speak=(Button)findViewById(R.id.takespeak);
        date=(Button)findViewById(R.id.takedatebutton);
        from=(Button)findViewById(R.id.takefrom);
        to=(Button)findViewById(R.id.taketo);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.takelistview);
        al=new ArrayList<String>();
        present=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.present);
        present.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,al);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        checkall=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkall);
        datesp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //checkall.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        assign();

        //database
        db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/Attendance/database.db",null);



        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spitem=(String)sp.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                final ArrayList<String> ss= new ArrayList<String>();

                SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/Attendance/database.db",null);
                Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("select numbers from Main where class='"+spitem+"'", null);
                if(cr!=null)
                {
                    if(cr.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do{
                            String pp =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("numbers"));
                            String[]  pp1=pp.split(",");
                            for(int i=0; i<pp1.length;i++)
                            {
                                ss.add(pp1[i]);
                            }
                            Log.e("data",cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("numbers")));
                        }while(cr.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"spitem="+spitem,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                adapter=new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),1, 0,ss);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        setlist();



    }
```

ListAdapter File:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int i, int i1, List<String> objects) {
        this.context=context;
        listData =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        for(String value : objects){
            HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            row.put("value",value);
            row.put("isChecked",Boolean.valueOf(false));
            listData.add(row);
        }
    }

    public int selectedItemsSize(){
        int size = 0;
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            if((Boolean)row.get("isChecked")){
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    public ArrayList<String>  getSelected(){
        ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            if((Boolean)row.get("isChecked")){
                selected.add(row.get("value").toString());
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }

    public void checkAll(){
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            row.put("isChecked",true);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void uncheckAll(){
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            row.put("isChecked",false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listrowtext);
            holder.ckbox =(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listrowcheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).get("value").toString());
        holder.ckbox.setChecked((Boolean) listData.get(position).get("value"));
        holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                listData.get(position).put("isChecked",isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


    static class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox ckbox;
    }
```

}

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listrowtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/listrowcheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Emulator log report:**
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
at works.Attendance.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:101)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: now am able to check all check box but when i call "pre = adapter.selectedItemsSize();" from Take1 file it return 0 and am not getting checkbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Take ArrayList of HashMap which hold your list string value as well as list item check state 
and define checkAll and uncheckAll two custom method for check all and uncheck all list item,change list item check state on OnCheckedChangeListener base on item position.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,List<String> objects) {
        this.context=context;
        listData =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        for(String value : objects){
            HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            row.put("value",value);
            row.put("isChecked",Boolean.valueOf(false));
            listData.add(row);
        }
    }

    public int selectedItemsSize(){
        int size = 0;
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            if((Boolean)row.get("isChecked")){
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    public ArrayList<String>  getSelected(){
        ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            if((Boolean)row.get("isChecked")){
                selected.add(row.get("value").toString());
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }

    public void checkAll(){
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            row.put("isChecked",true);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void uncheckAll(){
        for(HashMap<String,Object> row : listData){
            row.put("isChecked",false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listrowtext);
            holder.ckbox =(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listrowcheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).get("value").toString());
        holder.ckbox.setChecked((Boolean) listData.get(position).get("value"));
        holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                listData.get(position).put("isChecked",isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


    static class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox ckbox;
    }

}
```

Comment: for above List adapter is there any changes required in my main file. my main file code updated in my question.please see once.

Comment: @Murali,Glad to help you and if ans is resolve your problem then you can approve ans so it may help others solve same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method inside your `ListAdapter` and iterate over all items, checking if the view is `instance of CheckBox` and then do the job?

```
public ListAdapter ... {

    public void checkAll() {
        for (int position = 0; position < getCount(); position++) {
            final View view = getView(i);
            if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
                ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If I'm mystaken, please show yout `R.layout.list_row` layout file.

Comment: Thank you for resonance.Please do this favor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489901/how-to-check-all-checkboxes-in-a-listview

Comment: how can i call is checkAll() from main file

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean **"problem is it only showing all check box's checked and return's how many box'x checked"** ?

You don't have to make new instance of adapter every time, just update the check state in List and notify data changed, then the getView will be called to update the listview